# Apply 3 sigma formula in gamma distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, gamma-distribution

Let say i have some data that follows gamma distribution, and i calculated the Mean and Standard deviation of the gamma distribution.

I also know that there are some outliers(Noise) in the data i want to exclude.

Now ,

Is it OK to take Mean+ 3 sigma to cover almost (99.7 %) all data ( like Normal distribution) ?
My target is to exclude the data those are not inside 3 sigma considering as a noise. does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like 3 sigma consideration is kind of acceptable.

While the area within three standard deviations of the mean does drop slightly at first, it stabilizes for the J-shaped Gammas at about 97.5 percent. This means that a fixed-width, three-standard-deviation central interval for a Gamma distribution will always contain at least 97.5 percent of that distribution.

For more details : [Properties of Probability Models, Part 2](https://www.qualitydigest.com/inside/six-sigma-column/090115-properties-probability-models-part-2.html)